# SSH hangs while executing remote script from a Daemon

Tags: ssh, redhat, solaris-11

I have a script which gets hanged while doing SSH from a Daemon , whereas it works perfectly while I run it from the terminal.

- Source Machine - redhat-rhel7.3-EUS-x86_64
- Remote Machine - Solaris 11.4

```
ssh XXXXXX << EOF
echo "Start executing script" >>/app/temp.log
/app/script.ksh 1 2 >> /app/temp.log
echo "finish executing script" >>/app/temp.log
exit 0
EOF

echo "Final execution completed">>/app/temp.log
```

1. RUN 1 - From terminal (User X) , the script get completed and there will be no process running
2. RUN 2 - From Daemon(Running on User X) , the script stuck at EOF I believe , as I can see log file has "finish executing script" , and I can see process running

What should I do to make script work?

PS - script.ksh exists in the remote server

Comment: Can you ssh to the remote server when the script is hanging?  You should be able to see your ssh session in the output of `ps`.  See if there are any child processes it's waiting on.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The script gets completed ,  I can see the last echo in the log file